# IntegerColumn not available in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I am new to GWT and  I am trying to make a simple table in GWT.
The table has string and integer types.
However, GWT  has only TextColumns which returns only Strings.

But there is no "IntegerColumns" which returns Integers, so what's the easiest way to design it ?

Right now I convert Integers to Strings but this solution is not suitable for sorting the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use Grid? Grid is able to store objects as rows;
For example you want to have a look [Grid](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwGrid)

And maybe you'd like to see [GXT samples](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#basicgrid)